# NA when finding correlation in a dataframe

Tags: r, correlation, na

I am trying to calculate correlation for my data frame i.e. df3 which looks like this

```
    group          a         b  
1  01_01-102_PRT  0.5857299 1.0915944  
2    01_1014_EMH -0.8875033 0.9982261  
3  02_02-012_ABT  1.5402289 1.0095046  
4 02_02-028B_TMA -0.2635421 0.9533909  
5    02_097A_KMG  0.1529145 1.0452099  
6     02_116_DMC  0.7375643 0.9927591
```

My code:

```
require(plyr)
func <- function(df3)
{
    return(data.frame(COR = cor(df3$a, df3$b)))
}

too <- ddply(df3, .(group), func)
```

My output

```
     group          COR  
1    01_01-102_PRT  NA
2      01_1014_EMH  NA
3    02_02-012_ABT  NA
4   02_02-028B_TMA  NA
5      02_097A_KMG  NA
....
```

I have also tried other ways given here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group but I always get NAs.

Help please
Thanks
Jason

Comment: As Sven suggests, you may not be aggregating your data the way you think you are.  Try writing out the equations (math, not code) and see where you get.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that each group consists of exactly one row and therefore of one `a` and one `b` value. You cannot calculate correlation if there's no variation in the data. Hence, you need at least two *different* values for both `a` and `b`.